# Can you make classes in a loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass

I have a situation where I'm making a bunch of classes, and a bunch of them are really basically the same, so I'd like to make them in a loop. They are being used with a registration system, so there's no problem one the USAGE side, but I'm not sure how to actually define a class with a variable determining the class name...

Simple example:

```
classList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

for className in classList:
    class {{{className}}}_calc(BaseCalc): 
         def __init__ (self, dataFrame):
             self.column = dataFrame[className]
         def calc ():
             return self.column.sum()
```

This is a very simplified case, obviously. I can't change the arguments to **init** because there are a whole bunch of these already existing, that are part of a larger structure.

The rest of the example is using pandas syntax, just to give an idea of how this is being used... but it's actually being used with a SQL DB, and is much more complicated... I just don't want to have to defend "why are you doing this in the first place?" I have good reasons, leave it at that.

classname is in {{{ }}} in the class line to denote that it's a variable, and not actually syntactically correct there. The question is "how do I denote what I have used {{{ }}} for?" I think.

The answer may be metaclasses, but I'm still not sure how to make the NAME of my class variable....

ETA: Trying to use @python_user answer:

```
classList = ['foooo', 'bar', 'baaz']

class Base ():
    def __init__ (self, buq):
        self.buq = buq

    def getBuq(self):
        return 'buq: ' + self.buq
    

for cls in classList:
    class TEMP(Base):
        className = cls
        def __init__ (self):
            self.qux = len(cls)
            Base.__init__(self, cls)

        def blee(self, inpt):
            return inpt+ self.qux
    TEMP.__name__ = f'{cls}'
    TEMP.__qualname__ = f'{cls}'
    globals()[cls] = TEMP
f = foo()

f.getBuq()

>>>> 'buq: baaz'
```

This is only giving me the baaz class. All three are giving baaz...  Am I doing something really dumb?

Comment: use type() to create a class with a dynamically assigned name, ``type(f"MyClass{number}", (), {})``. You'll have to stuff in bases and dict appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like so, using `globals()`

```
classList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

for className in classList:
    class Temp:
        def __init__ (self, dataFrame):
            self.column = dataFrame[className]
        def calc ():
            return self.column.sum()
    Temp.__name__ = className
    globals()[className] = Temp
```

You can then do `foo()` to create an object of class `foo`. You have to call with the args required for the `__init__` method for the actual example. This is just to show it works.

```
print(type(foo()).__name__) # foo
print(type(bar()).__name__) # bar
print(type(baz()).__name__) # baz
```

If you want to change your class names then you can do

```
Temp.__name__ = f'{className}_calc'
globals()[f'{className}_calc'] = Temp
```

As pointed out by wim in the comments you need to also set `__qualname__`. `Temp.__qualname__ = f'{className}_calc'`

Edit:

As name lookups in methods of a class are performed at runtime (not at compile time), the code snippet has a bug. `className` would always refer to the last element in the `classList` (`baz` in this case), this name exists outside the scope of the loop and will be the value for `className` in the methods for ALL classes. (eg : `self.column = dataFrame[className]`).  <--- This is always `dataFrame['baz']`

To fix this, one has to declare a class level variable called `className` and assign `className` (the one from the loop) to that. So at compile time this value will be bound to the class. All reference to `className` inside the methods of the class needs to be changed to `self.className` for the code to work as expected.

```
class Temp:
    className = className # note this line
    def __init__ (self, dataFrame):
        self.column = dataFrame[self.className] # and this line with the original snippet
```

Comment: Probably the least gross of the solutions here.  You should set `__qualname__` as well.

Comment: I like the idea of this answer, but it's not working. I'll add my code into the question text...

Comment: Ok ,so if I replace the 1st line with cls=cls, and use self.cls instead of cls everywhere, it works! thanks!

Comment: yeah thats what I meant by that, didnt find that bug out until after an hour of posting the answer, glad to know it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type function, however, to create such dynamic classes. names = ['name1', 'name2'] Suppose you have to create 10 class objects in python, and do something with them, like: obj_1 = MyClass() other_object.

Hope I could help you.

Comment: I think this may work, I'm currently trying something like this with: type(className+'calc', BaseCalc, {......}. But the dictionary gets very complicated because it has a lot of lambdas that are multiple lines... hmm

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a a kind of messy way to do this using the "exec()" function which takes any string and executes it; then you can build your classes as a string and run that. Here is an example which builds your classes, you can see that they are declared by looking in the global namespace which is printed at the end.

```py
classList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

class BaseCalc(): 
     def __init__ (self, dataFrame):
         self.column = dataFrame[className]
     def calc ():
         return self.column.sum()

for className in classList:
    template = '''class %s_calc(BaseCalc): 
         def __init__ (self, dataFrame):
             self.column = dataFrame[className]
         def calc ():
             return self.column.sum()''' % className
    exec(template)

print(globals())
```